# Primary Constructor in c#12, Jetbrains Rider

Tags: c#, rider

i am trying out the new primary constructors for c# 12 but getting the error

`Invalid option '12' for /langversion. Use '/langversion:?' to list supported values.`

while I have my project properties like below.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <LangVersion>12</LangVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

My code which i am trying to run is as fallows.

```
Employee employee1 = new Employee("John Doe", 30);

Employee.DisplayInfo();

public class Employee(string name, int age)
{
    public void DisplayInfo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Name: {name}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Age: {age}");
    }
}
```

i am trying out the new primary constructors for c# 12 but getting the error, I am not able to understand where i am doing wrong, it should work as expected.

Comment: Which Rider version are you using? C# 12 and primary constructor support was [added in 2023.2](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2023/05/15/rider-2023-2-eap1/). C# 12 comes with .NET 8, not .NET 7. You'll have to change `<TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>` to ` <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, C# 12 comes with the .NET 8 runtime. You need to install the .NET 8 SDK and change the target framework to `net8.0`

```xml
 <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
```

Second, you need to use a Rider version that does support C# 12 and primary constructors. Support for primary constructors was [first added in Rider 2023.2 EAP 9](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2023/07/14/rsrp-rider-2023-2-eap9/). If you use 2023.2, you should be able to create a project that targets .NET 8 and can use primary constructors.

Comment: i saw a video on youtube and it showed that it worked with dotnet 7.0

https://youtu.be/Slvyugn458Q?si=z0SkgLyhDD7jFYOm

Comment: In which exact second? Did the speaker install .NET 8 SDK before that? You can't use a feature that isn't supported by the compiler, which is part of the SDK. Once you install the .NET 8 SDK you can create a project that targets .NET 7 but uses C# 12 *as long as* you don't use any features that require explicit runtime support.